# How do we make sure that companion wear watch application is updated when android phone app is updated?

Tags: android, wear-os

We have an application for which some events & command messages can be provided by our wear companion application ( Not the standalone one )

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="false" />
```

Now, these two applications make use of some predefined format of messages for synching the commands. At the time of release, we make sure both wear & android apks has the similar compatible message versions so the communication between them happens without a problem.

But apks prior 2-3 versions may make use of some older format of messages which may stop working if phone apk is updated & wear apk stays the older.

Do wear OS have any APIs which make sure that if phone application is updated to latest the companion application on wear also gets updated to latest?